# How do I lock a gameObject to the origin

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make sure certain gameObjects in my hierarchy do not move from the origin. Most of them are just parent objects with no purpose other than to hold child objects. A built in Unity function, an asset from the asset store, or just a script would work fine. I don't want to set any objects to the origin at runtime I want to lock them there while editing.

I have tried looking through stackoverflow and the unity docs for something that would do what I want and could not find anything. PositionConstraint was the closest thing I found but I don't think it does what I want.

Edit:
I (or somebody I'm working with) sometimes move things that should not be moved. For example I might move the gameObject with multiple houses in it and move that around a bit because I moved the road, which is not what I want to happen. I want to instead limit myself to selecting all the houses and moving them like that.

Comment: Have you tried `ExecuteAlways` attribute and then setting the position in the `Update` - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html . I'm not in front of a PC so I can't test it right now.

Comment: normally things only move because you let them.. in what way is something moving which you dont want?

Comment: I (or somebody I'm working with) sometimes move things that should not be moved. For example I might move the gameObject with multiple houses in it and move that around a bit because I moved the road, which is not what I want to happen. I want to instead limit myself to selecting all the houses and moving them like that.